# Use: docker build -t myapp . cannot get image successfully

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Docker file is :

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]
EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "project.json", "kestrel"]
```

Has anything wrong in my Docker file?

Below are response:

```
Restore failed
A task was canceled.
NuGet Config files used:
    /root/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config
Feeds used:
    https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
The command 'dnu restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: so what's the error you got?

Comment: Please add the build output to your question

Comment: I add the response, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker file need updated as below, then ok for build:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta4
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "./src/HelloMvc6", "kestrel"]
```

Comment: there is no reason for replacing `COPY` with `ADD` in this case

Comment: I refer to this link, and try as link said, it is successfully.https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Running-ASP.NET-5-beta4-in-Docker-with-DNX-runtime/#dockerfile2

Comment: And since you solved your issue, you should accept your own answer